# I am struggling to import "wmi" in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

i am using py 3.6 and whenever i type this:

```
import wmi

def avg(value_list):
    num = 0
    length = len(value_list)
    for val in value_list:
        num += val
    return num/length


w = wmi.WMI(namespace=r"C:\Users\name\Desktop\OpenHardwareMonitor")
sensors = w.Sensor()
cpu_temps = []
gpu_temp = 0
for sensor in sensors:
    if sensor.SensorType==u'Temperature' and not 'GPU' in sensor.Name:
        cpu_temps += [float(sensor.Value)]
    elif sensor.SensorType==u'Temperature' and 'GPU' in sensor.Name:
        gpu_temp = sensor.Value
print("Avg CPU: {}").format(avg(cpu_temps))
print("GPU: {}").format(gpu_temp)
```

it comes out as:

```
PS C:\Users\name> & C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe "c:/Users/name/gpu temps.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/name/pip install gpiozero.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wmi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wmi'
```

i went through alot of the options on the web and 1 other post and went through all the options, including " pywin32-300.win-amd64-py3.6.exe" on https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases...
still doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure you've installed it into the environment you're using?

Comment: `pip install wmi`

Comment: @Vulpex after relooking at it, as i was sure i did. a new problem came up, it was downloading, but to py 3.9 even though my python path was to C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe (instead of C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe). do you know how to fix that?

Comment: `python39 -m pip install wmi` before that make sure `which python39` python39 is defined. But, as @Vulpex suggested, I would suggest you use virtualenv in your laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to the details given in the comments.

What I would generally suggest is to create virtual environments for each python project you have.

in visual studio code here is how you could do it:

- Open your project folder with VS-Code
- open the terminal inside VS-Code
- execute `C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe -m venv env` (or the path to your python installation you'd like to create a virtual environment of)
- activate your enviornment by entering `. .\env\Scripts\Activate.ps1` (assuming windows, you might need to enter `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process` to allow execution

now you should have a little (env) shown in the terminal, indicatung you're using the virtual environment.

next you can enter all the pip install commands you need for your project.